# How to fire a loader on ajax in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, loader

I have created a navigation in vanilla js with ajax, so the site is not refreshing, just the content in my div class='ajax_container'. When I click on an element in my navigation, I start first change the innerHTML of my ajax_container to my loader, witch is/are some html div-tags and start an ajax-call. If the status of this is 4 I change the innerHTML of my ajax_container to the responseText.

Now my question is, what is the good style for doing this. It's working perfect but feels unnatural like I archived my goal.

```
xhr.onloadstart = function () {
document.getElementById("ajax_container").innerHTML = "<div class='ring_loader'><div class='loader_ring_rotate'><div class='loader_ring' id='loader_ring_scale_one'></div></div><div class='loader_ring_rotate'><div class='loader_ring' id='loader_ring_scale_two'></div></div></div>";}
```

The css for my loader is included in the header of the whole page and defines, of course, the style and transitions.

Comment: Just show the loader before calling `xhr.send()`, and remove it in the `xhr.onreadystatechange` function.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you have a loader which is "hidden" so style="display: none;"
Or add the whole loader to the DOM if you really want to, can do as well, same logic-ish.

Then you fire your AJAX request (that lives in a function), first show the loader block (so unhide), and in the callback block (response is your ajax response) you hide the loader again.

Something like:

```
function (On click of element {
    // Show spinner (so display = block or flex or whatever of that element)

    doAjaxRequest(parameters, function(callback) {
        // throw response into DOM (so callback.data or what you name it)
        // Hide spinner again
    });
});
```

I hope that makes sense, I can extend the answer if needed but I hope you get the gist of it. (let me know if needed)

Comment: Sounds good, but I thought, it would be nice to just really implemented the spinner, if it is needed. So after the ajax-call the loader is replaced through the responseText and the loader is gone.  I mean with your solution I have to require a php-script in each file, that I'm loading with ajax because the loader should be shown in the ajax_container itself and not on the whole page. It would be nice to put the loader divs in a own file and reference to these after the innerHTML =

Answer (score 0):

mm ok, yes I would keep the spinner in a completely separate container (div) that you just show/hide via JS (like the example via a callback).

Your PHP side ONLY returns your AJAX response (how you already have that (without a spinner obv). I don't know what you mean with that you have to include a PHP script in every file with my solution? What I'm showing happens all in JS (obviously not YOUR AJAX request like how it's always been).

But if you REALLY want to ONLY have the spinner in your DOM when it actually "spins", than just do the same as my example above but instead of "Show spinner" you actually "Add spinner" to your `"ajax_container".innerHTML` and then AFTER the AJAX response has loaded you simply replace the `"ajax_container".innerHTML` again but then with that what you actually want to show?

So if get you correctly, ideally you don't want a "loader" to always be on your page but ONLY when your AJAX actually "loads".
So yes, if that's the case just in stead of show/hide div do "add spinner html / add other html".

Comment: You are right, I don't have to include the spinner in the PHP script, that I'm loading. My fault. I just wanted to reduce the coder after the "ajax_container".innerHTML and have the spinner in my DOM when the ajax is loading. So maybe get it out of another html file, but my try with <object> was horrible and so I decided to let it be, like it is. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: ok all good, as long as it works for you